# JSON security issues?

Tags: json

Are there any security issues in using JSON for just data transfer, other than that it is plain text? Like, the eval() which poses a security issue when used in JavaScript. Are there any such issues, when JSON is just used to transfer data between computers and read by programs written in Java etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.xml.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/3370

**http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html**

Comment: Using the Internet Wayback Machine ... https://web.archive.org/web/20130105115704/http://www.xml.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/3370 https://web.archive.org/web/20090814040102/http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/03/05/json_is_not_as_safe_as_people_think_it_is.html

Answer (score 1):

> JSON can be used to execute JavaScript
>   insertion attacks against any web
>   client that uses it, unless the server
>   (and only the server) takes
>   appropriate precautions.

Comment: Well, I am planning to use it only for data transfer that is used by programs other than JavaScript, in that case would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Sending out passwords unencrypted using JSON would be clearly a security issue. In general, JSON itself are just bytes; it's the interpretation that's given to them which may cause harm.